# Ajax запрос при отправке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

Как отправить данные через `Ajax` методом `GET`?
Можно ли вообще отправлять данные на сервер через `Ajax` методом `GET`?

Comment: Возможно поможет библиотека jquery и метод [`jquery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Имеется в виду язык javascript ведь?

Comment: Возможно, но не нужно, GET для этого не предназначен

Comment: @diraria да я имею в виду jquery.ajax()

Comment: @andreymal а для чего?

Comment: @KetyLi https://translate.google.ru/#en/ru/get

Comment: Ох уж мне эти наводящие вопросы .... С одной стороны конечно хороший подход в обучении, но некоторых вводится в ступор ... В общем то что хочет сказать andreymal: GET служит для того что бы "получать", а POST что бы "отдавать" данные (то есть ваша формулировка немного неверна, когда вы говорите "отправлять методом GET") .... обратиться к серверу через ajax с методом GET можно, более того, `$.ajax()` по дефолту отправляет запросы с GET, если не указать другой метод.

Answer (score 1):

вот от одного из [известного источника](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

```
// 1. Создаём новый объект XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Конфигурируем его: GET-запрос на URL 'phones.json'
xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', false);

// 3. Отсылаем запрос
xhr.send();

// 4. Если код ответа сервера не 200, то это ошибка
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  // обработать ошибку
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
  // вывести результат
  alert( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
```